# Calling function in another class in another file in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have 2 classes in 2 different files:

fileA.py

```
class A(self):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func_A(self):
        print '10'
```

fileB.py

```
import fileA
class B(self):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func_B(self):
            print '10'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = B()
    # Call func_A
    fileA.func_A()
```

The call to func_A fails.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func_A'
```

How can I make it work correctly?

Comment: `func_A` isn't just in module `fileA` it's on an instance of class `A` from module `fileA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As using class , you should create an instance of Class A.

```
a = fileA.A()
a.func_A()
```